# writing a function that return the reversed number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a Python function that get a number as `input` and returns its reversed number as `output`. for example: 1234 returns 4321.

this is what I try, but it return only `''`

```
def reverse(num):
  L=[]
  x=str(num)
  L1=list(x)

  for i in L1:
    L.insert(0,i)
  print 'the reversed num is:'

  x=''
  for i in L:
    x.join(i)
    return x
```

any ideas?

Comment: read about `pythonic way` and `zen of python` (type `import this` in interpreter)

Comment: @AlexeyAstahov that's not very helpful.

Comment: @timgeb write 9 lines instead of one line is not very helpful. Python is not C/C++ or smth. Topicstarter must learn how to think more pythonic. And my helpful answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35267069/5198288

Comment: "Think more pythonic" is *not* a helpful answer to a specific question. I did not see that you posted a helpful answer as well - sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 3):

```
def reverse(num):
    return str(num)[::-1]
```

or one line:

```
lambda x: str(x)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easy solution is this one:

```
>>> int(str(1234)[::-1])
4321
```

Your code can be fixed by changing the part

```
for i in L:
    x.join(i)
    return x
```

to

```
for i in L:
    x += i
return x
```

Alternatively, just replace that section by

```
return ''.join(L)
```

What was wrong with your code? Because of wrong indentation, you returned in the first iteration of the for loop. You never assigned a name to `x.join(i)` so the return value was lost. What you expected `join` to do I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is an easier way by converting to string, slicing the string and converting it back to a number.

```
def reverse(num):
    return int(str(num)[::-1])
```

Second, there are multiple errors in your code:

1) your return statement is in the loop, so it will return after the first iteration;

2) `x` does not change because `x.join()` creates a new string and does not modify the string `x` (which is immutable by the way)

3) no need to convert the string into a list since you can directly iterate over the string (`for i in x: ...`)

4) `join()` takes an iterator as an argument. No need for the second loop: `return ''.join(L)`

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for the helpful ideas.

here is my solution:

```
         def reverse(n):
            reverse=0
            while(n>0):
                    dig=n%10
                    reverse=reverse*10
                    reverse=reverse+dig
                    n=n/10
            return reverse
```

Comment: correction: 
reverse=0
while(n>=1):
    dig=n%10
    reverse=reverse*10
    reverse=reverse+dig
    n=n//10
print(reverse)

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse(num)
    return str(num)[::-1]
```

[Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Other users already gave good answers. Here is a different one, for study purposes.

```
num = 1234
print "".join(reversed(str(num)))
# 4321
```

You can convert to int afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
reverse=0
while(n>=1):
    dig=n%10
    reverse=reverse*10
    reverse=reverse+dig
    n=n//10
print(reverse)
```